# Метод getView вызывается больше, чем надо

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть словарь у которого длина равна 2 м.
И значит `getView()` должен вызываться стольок же.
Но он вызывается 5 раз. Как это понять?

Код адаптера:

```
public class DailyActivityAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<ManagerData> list;
    private Map<String,List<ManagerData>>hashReportListMap;
    private String[] mKeys;


    public DailyActivityAdaptor(Context context, Map<String, List<ManagerData>> hashReportListMap) {
        this.context = context;
        this.hashReportListMap = hashReportListMap;
        mKeys = hashReportListMap.keySet().toArray(new String[hashReportListMap.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return hashReportListMap.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return hashReportListMap.get(mKeys[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                    inflate(R.layout.daily_activity_views, parent, false);
        }
         String key  = mKeys[position];
        List<ManagerData> currentItem = hashReportListMap.get(key);

        Log.e("count ", " " +  hashReportListMap.size());


        TextView SBE_NAME = (TextView)
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.daily_activity_sbe_name);
        TextView SBE_CODE = (TextView)
                convertView.findViewById(R.id.daily_activity_sbe_code);

        SBE_NAME.setText(currentItem.get(0).getUserName());
        SBE_CODE.setText(currentItem.get(0).getUserSbe());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Comment: @Suvitruf точно спасибо большое!Штаны полной радости и забыл )))

Comment: Был рад помочь (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть словарь у которого длина равна 2 м. И значит getView() должен
>   вызываться стольокж.

Нет, нету никакого порядка в вызове `getView()`, точно так же как нельзя точно сказать, сколько раз он будет вызван, особенно если у вашего `ListView` в разметке стоит `height=wrap_content`, что вынуждает пересчитывать размер потомков, чтоб фактический размер свой узнать.